# Hover-list in CSS Only

Tags: html, css

I'm having some trouble with CSS rollover menus.

I've seen it a lot, and there are tutorials, but there is so much unnecessary code, and I find it hard to distinguish between which is the needed code, and which is just other CSS.

I'd like to have a hover menu on CSS only because the website I'm working on has a lot of users that intentionally have scripting disabled (JavaScript).

I don't understand, in CSS, how one can make a "sub menu" appear beneath its parent List item when the user hovers over the parent list item. Can someone please help me understand how this works in CSS?

Below is an image of what I am referring to:

> [image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The following will work, in its basic form, but style for your own tastes (position, borders, colours, etc):

```
<ul>
    <li>Simple List item
        <ul>
            <li>sub menu item 1</li>
            <li>sub menu item 2</li>
            <li>sub menu item 3</li>
       </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

With the CSS:

```
ul li {
    position: relative;
}

ul ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 1em;
    left: 0;
    display: none;
}

ul > li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/4fsaC/1/).

Comment: Thank you. It does actually show and hide when hovered. But, no matter what top or left I set, or what position I set, the "sub" menu item only appears at the very top-left of the page (and the actual menu is on the right of the page and down a bit) -

Comment: Am I seeing things, or did some code in your answer just disappear?

Comment: Thank you @MiljanPuzović and thanks David Thomas - works just as I had hoped. So happy to finally understand how it's done! :-)

Comment: Yeah, the problem was that I'd forgotten to set `position: relative;` on the parent `li`; `position: absolute` elements are positioned relative to the first ancestor element with a `position` other than `static` (I think), or, otherwise, relative to the `body` element.